# Tree property using side conditions

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

The following problems were asked during the  [high and low forcing](http://aimath.org/pastworkshops/highlowforcing.html) workshop:

> **Question 1.** Can one force tree property at $\kappa^{++}$ for $\kappa$ singular using side conditions?
>
> **Question 2.** Can one force tree property at successive cardinals using side conditions?

As it is stated in [A report on the workshop activities](http://aimath.org/pastworkshops/highlowforcingrep.pdf), question 1 is solved during the conference.

**I wonder to know if there is any reference for the proof, or if someone can explain the basic ideas of the proof.**

**I am also interested to know if any progress on question 2 is obtained?** (I may mention that in Nemman's paper [Forcing with Sequences of Models of Two Types](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1398345784), this is claimed for two successive cardinals but no details are given).

Comment: I have two terminological qualms here: (1) it wasn't a conference it was a workshop; and (2) by side conditions do you mean Itay's constructions and the related ideas, or just the general term for a forcing with some additional structural conditions? (E.g. coding a subset of $\omega_1$ into a real is a Cohen forcing with side conditions.)

Comment: (Also I recognize at least a handful of faces which have active MO accounts, maybe one of them will pass around and answer. Which I'm sure is what you were hoping for, more or less.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks,  I changed conference to workshop. By side condition I mean Neeman's method.

Comment: In [Boban Velickovic's talk at the Magidor 70 conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HttGQ9kyt8&list=PLT-roSWIpp1Hvj2GNhztmfNIJ0Shtu2P8&index=11), he mentions (at the very end) that by an application of his pure side condition poset, he can get a model like Uri Abraham's, with the tree property holding at both $\aleph_2$ and $\aleph_3$. I don't think Neeman mentions this application in his original paper, only how to get the tree property at a single cardinal.